# Replace Text inside PowerPoint using Java

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx4j

I have a PPT containing values in the format: `{VALUES}`. I would like to replace the text of the file containing `{SAMPLE}` to `SARAN` and so on using Java. Earlier I tried with Apache poi and I had no solution but I could find that in Docx4j there is an method `variableReplace()` which will replace the text. I tried one sample but I don't see any text being replaced.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Docx4JException, Pptx4jException, JAXBException  
{
      String inputfilepath = "C:\\Work\\SampleTemplate.pptx"; 
      PresentationMLPackage pptPackage
          = PresentationMLPackage.load(new File(inputfilepath));
      ThemePart themeSlidePart = (ThemePart) 
          pptPackage.getParts().getParts().get(new PartName("/ppt/theme/theme1.xml"));
      Theme themeOfSlides = (Theme)themeSlidePart.getJaxbElement();                     
      SlidePart slide = pptPackage.getMainPresentationPart().getSlide(0);
      HashMap h = new HashMap<String, String>();
      h.put("SlideTitleName", "SARANYA");
      slide.variableReplace(h);
      String outputfilepath = "C:\\Work\\24Jan2018_CheckOut\\dhl\\PPT-TRAILS\\SampleTemplate.pptx";
      PresentationMLPackage pptPackagetoApply
          = PresentationMLPackage.load(new File(outputfilepath));
      ThemePart themeSlidePartToApply
          = (ThemePart) pptPackagetoApply.getParts().getParts()
              .get(new PartName("/ppt/theme/theme1.xml"));
      themeSlidePartToApply.setJaxbElement(themeOfSlides);
      SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(pptPackagetoApply);
      saver.save(outputfilepath);
}
```

But still text is not being replaced. I tried with a new PPTX file with  only text "${SlideTitleName}" inside it. But still it's not working.

---

I would like to add many rows to my pptx template using for loop, I tried the below,

### Java:

```
  if(majorAchievements.size()>0){

        System.out.println("majorAchievements Size in Servlet is : "+majorAchievements.size() + " and value of get(0) is : "+ majorAchievements.get(0) ); 

        for(int i=0;i<majorAchievements.size();i++){

            achievements=(String) majorAchievements.get(i);

        }
    }


mappings.put("MajorAchievementText", achievements);
```

and inside my ppt file ,

i haved added two rows with same ${MajorAchievementText}.

The above list fetches 2 rows. But inside ppt it is not replace.
Please help me how to replace an text by iterating.

With Regards,
Saranya C

Comment: Hi @saranya, welcome to StackOverflow. Please include a MCV example with inputs and errors (or expected/actual) outputs. See this article for more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tried to improve formatting, grammar and clarity.

Comment: Hi,   Im just trying an simple program to check if im able to replace a text inside Powerpoint. So have copied the main program here.If you want I will copy the whole  file so that you can check and advise me ,

Comment: its probably because Powerpoint has "split your run"; please post your SampleTemplate file somewhere, or add the XML content of the slide to your question.